# Monacaを使ってオープンストリートマップの地図データをオフライン上で表示する事は可能でしょうか

Tags: monaca, openstreetmap

Monacaでアプリを作成しているのですが、オープンストリートマップの地図情報を、オフライン上で表示することは可能でしょうか。
キャッシュではなく、アプリインストール時に一緒に地図データもダウンロードしていて、そのデータを表示するイメージです。

Comment: どれぐらいの大きさの物をローカルに保存しようと想定していますか？